# Returning TempData to my view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, viewdata

I am writing a simple booking system in MVC 4. When a booking is submitted using the form I want to redirect to the next page but I want to pass my model data.

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(CustomerBookingModel CustomerBooking)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                switch (CustomerBooking.Cancellation)
                {
                    case true:
                        //TODO: Data layer method for cancellation
                        CustomerBooking.ActionStatus = StatusCode.Cancelled.ToString();
                        break;
                    case false:
                        //TODO: Data layer method for making a booking in DB
                        CustomerBooking.ActionStatus = StatusCode.Booked.ToString();
                        break;
                }
                TempData["Model"] = CustomerBooking;
                return RedirectToAction("About");                
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

If my model is valid I do some logic based on the status of the booking. I then populate TempData which I want to access in ActionMethod about.

```
public ActionResult About()
        {
            if (TempData["Model"] != null)
            {
                var model = TempData["Model"];
                return View(model);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

What is a good way of displaying this data in the view?

```
@ViewData["Model"]
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}
```

My view is empty because I am using viewdata and not a model.

Comment: Can't you use @Model.PropertyName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since [`TempData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.aspx) will return an `object` you should try to cast it back.

#### Controller

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    var model = (TempData["Model"] as CustomerBookingModel)
                ?? new CustomerBookingModel();

    return View(model);
}
```

#### About.cshtml

```
@model CustomerBookingModel

@Html.DisplayForModel();
```

#### DisplayTemplates/CustomerBookingModel.cshtml

```
@model CustomerBookingModel

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.SomeProperty)
    <p>@Model.SomeProperty</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I will try your suggestion

Comment: You create the `DisplayTemplates` folder under the `views/controller` directory. There is also `EditorTemplates` which work for `Html.EditorForModel`.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly! That is the first time I have seen casting back to a model. I will remember this for the future!